# Best way for product export for a list of skus

Tags: magento-1.9, product, export

Is there a best practice for a product export in Magento (1.9.0.1 CE) for a given sku list? It should be a full export with all attributes. It's required for an import into another Magento shop.

The dataflow profile doesn't provide this feature. So, I guess I have to do the export programmatically?

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Why won't the dataflow profile work?

Comment: There is no way to set a list of product skus for the export. Or I just don't see it?

Comment: You should be able to easily use sku as a filter: http://lero9.co.nz/magento-tips/how-to-export-your-magento-product-database-using-using-magentos-importexport-dataflow-profiles/

Comment: The sku-filter has the hint "starts with" I guess I can't enter a list of skus

Comment: Not sure (don't have time atm to look), but you should be able to do a comma delimited list or something, or add more skus... if not ditch excel (which I never use bc it's row limitation) and try something like http://www.delimitware.com/

Comment: Just checked the app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Adapter/Product.php and the code for sku is $attrFilterArray ['sku'] = 'startsWith'; But I don't see any other attribute with "in". Maybe there is no "in"-Feature implemented

Comment: app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Convert/Adapter/Entity.php
public function setFilter contains the supported ways to filter, there is no "in", only eq, like, startsWith, fromTo, dateFromTo, datetimeFromTo :/

Answer (score 2):

I've still not used Dataflow Profiles and any native import/export feature of Magento. But indeed, you could do it programmatically by browsing the products listed in the given sku list, and export the products and its attributes.

Comment: And if I have a million products? I'm going to browse them all?

Comment: Well, if you need to choose specific products, i don't see another way.

Comment: Ya thats your problem, we have to many products and Excel can't handle it to filter by sku after the export.